# How do you handle closures that return Any? type in swift?

Tags: swift, function, closures, any

I noticed that sometimes calling a function returns an Any? type.

One such example is the AccessToken.refreshCurrentAccessToken method from the Facebook Login iOS SDK.

The data that comes back is of type "Any?"

How do you correctly handle this type when you don't know what it contains?

What is the correct way to anticipate and handle a function that returns the Any? type in swift?

Example:

```
 AccessToken.refreshCurrentAccessToken { (connection:GraphRequestConnection?, data:Any?, error:Error?) in
    if error != nil {
        print("error")
        return
    }
            
    print("no error: data is /(data)")
 }
```

In this case, data returns the following in the debugger. But theres no way to know ahead of time what is in it.

```
(lldb) po data
▿ Optional<Any>
  ▿ some : 1 element
    ▿ 0 : 2 elements
      - key : data
      ▿ value : 3 elements
        ▿ 0 : 2 elements
          ▿ 0 : 2 elements
            - key : status
            - value : granted
          ▿ 1 : 2 elements
            - key : permission
            - value : email
        ▿ 1 : 2 elements
          ▿ 0 : 2 elements
            - key : status
            - value : granted
          ▿ 1 : 2 elements
            - key : permission
            - value : openid
        ▿ 2 : 2 elements
          ▿ 0 : 2 elements
            - key : status
            - value : granted
          ▿ 1 : 2 elements
            - key : permission
            - value : public_profile
```

Comment: If the author of the method intentionally decides to return to you "Any?", does that imply they don't really intend you to use the actual data returned?

Do they just want me to know that "something" is returned and that is enough to assume all was well? (In this case that the access token refreshes successfully)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this specific case, it doesn't look like any useful information will be returned in that parameter. According to the docs:

> An optional callback handler that can surface any errors related to permission refreshing.

In a more general sense, you'd have to know *some* sort of information about what `Any?` might contain and then you could do a type match with `as?` such as:

```
if let d = data as? Data {

}
```

See: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TypeCasting.html

Then, inside `{ }` you have access to a typed version if it passed the match successfully. But, again, you'd have to know what types you might encounter to do such a test.

Comment: When I use the debugger i can see that it returns a dictionary and some data points.

When the author of the method decides to return an Any?, is it implied that maybe the intent is to not try and use the specific data, but rather just assume its existence is "success"?

Comment: No, it's probably a holdover from Objective-C where there was less implicit type safety. It's definitely bad design in Swift. If it's a dictionary, you can probably cast it to `Dictionary<String,Any>` using the method above and then test the values for certain types as well. In this case, though, it looks like as long as you're not getting an error with this particular function, you're probably in good shape. Is there something you think you need from that dictionary?

Comment: In this case it does return a dictionary that tells me the status of various grants, like if i still have access to the FB users email address.

Comment: Then you can use the cast to Dictionary method I mentioned above.

Comment: Seems risky, since I can assume its a dictionary now, but its underlying values could change in the future and break at run time. I think its best for me to not use it at all and assume "success" when its not empty and thats the only thing that can be consistently implied.

Comment: It's true that the underlying values could change. However, as long as you're using `as?` to coerce the type in the cast, there's no risk of crash. Just don't use `as!`, which absolutely will crash.